# How to enable horizontal scrolling on mousewheel without pressing shift button

Tags: jquery

I'm using a horizontal scroll tumblr theme made by shythemes.tumblr.com, and I'd like to scroll horizontally simply on mousewheel, without pressing the shift button on keyboard, like [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/).

Not sure where did I go wrong, I tried from 'overflow:hidden' to jQuery, but none of the solution I found on internet worked.

Here's my entire website: http://morriew.tumblr.com/.

Thanks for answering in advance.

Comment: According to the article you linked to you need to include both jquery and the mousewheel plugin `jquery.mousewheel.min.js` I cannot see the mousewheel plugin on your site, you will need to add it first.

Comment: @lharby Sorry for late reply. I've added it onto the code according to your advise, but it seemed nothing happened. I have no idea, but it's really nice of you to answer me anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find instruction here [horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/)

1) Load jQuery and the Mouse Wheel plugin

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>
```

2) Attach mousewheel event to body

```
$("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
  this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```